# Adding entries to nested json in Golang

Tags: json, go, interface

I need to create a nested JSON in Go. Then, on runtime, append values into inner object, and those values will be of different types. This is why I initiate a interface{}.

```
i := map[string]interface{}{"name":"name"}
t := map[string]interface{}{"internal":internal_map}

if somestuff != ""{
template_map["internal"]["somestuff"] = somestuff
}

if somestuff2 != true{
template_map["internal"]["somestuff2"] = somestuff2
}
```

Now, the code above does not run due to `type interface {} does not support indexing` error.

I need all 3 - nested JSON, different types and run-time construction of internal object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line number two to

`t := map[string]map[string]interface{}{"internal":internal_map}`

Access it like this `t["internal"]["key_in_internal_map"]`.

This is essentially a map of maps. You can add as many embedded levels as you want.

Goplayground [example](https://play.golang.org/p/0644j5qz1i).
Although I would recommend making nested structs to avoid map chaining.